# webpack 4 - production mode - UglifyJs error - unexpected character '@'

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs, css-loader

When running webpack 4 with `mode: production`, I got the following error:

`ERROR in style.ba47861224d5cf44f61f.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected character '@' [./app/scss/main/app.scss:1,0][style.ba47861224d5cf44f61f.js:1,0]`

Here is my config:

common.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./webpack.entry.js",
        style: "./app/scss/main/app.scss"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                        cacheDirectory: true
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./app/html/index.html"
        })
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    }
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"
});

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractSass.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                url: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "sass-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [extractSass, new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin()],
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"
    },
    mode: "production"
});
```

I don't understand why is UglifyJs complaining about special character '@'. Shouldn't such characters be removed from `css-loader` already?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue! The `filename` option for `ExtractTextPlugin` has wrong extension `js`. It should be `css` like this:

```
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].css"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify loaders to handle sass files like you did in `webpack.dev.js` configuration.

Comment: In webpack.dev.js I use `style-loader`, but I don't want to use that for production. I use `ExtractTextPlugin` as instructed [here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/). Not sure what is wrong.